# Release<Type>ArrayElements not actually releasing memory from the heap during JNI call?

Tags: java, android, opencv, java-native-interface

I am developing an Android application that interfaces with some Native C++ code (JNI). On the Java side, I pass a look up table (double array) and two Open-CV matrices over to the JNI (by reference) to then process the matrices with C++. While the JNI function call works for the first 15~20 times, the application crashes and restarts soon after. I am 99% sure this is an issue with me not properly freeing up memory on the heap.

I have looked at the Profiler to check what is going on with the memory and I see a consistent increase in memory usage with each JNI function call. Most of the memory allocation seems to be in the Native portion, and you can see this increase in the image below (increase coincides with the calls to the JNI function).
[image]

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_mygroup_productName_ImgProcUtils_interpVals(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */,
        jlong addrKSqrd,
        jint nRows,
        jint nCols,
        jdoubleArray yTaucVal,
        jlong addrTauc) {
    cv::Mat& kSqrd = *(cv::Mat*)addrKSqrd;
    cv::Mat& Tauc = *(cv::Mat*)addrTauc;
    jboolean isCopy;
    jdouble *elem = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(yTaucVal, &isCopy);
    float pixel;
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++) {
            pixel = kSqrd.at<float>(i, j);
            int value = (int)round(pixel * 65535);
            if (value < 0) {
                value = 0;
            } else if (value > 65535) {
                value = 65535;
            }
            Tauc.at<float>(i,j) = (jfloat)elem[value];
        }
    }
    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(yTaucVal, elem, JNI_ABORT);
}
```

As you can see, I am releasing the double array I "get" before the for loops, but it seems like we still have memory that is not being released. Do I have to do anything else to properly release the memory? Is there any additional data that I need to release?

Comment: Where do those `Mat` pointers come from? Are you sure that those aren't the ones that you're not freeing correctly?

Comment: These are OpenCV `Mat`s the I allocate in Java. These are allocated before the loop that calls these JNI functions repeatedly. I believe that I don't have to free up these given that these are just pointers to the same Mats, I am not allocating any new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it's releasing issue.

If I have super simple Java code like this

```
package recipeNo026;

public class PassArray {

  public static native void passDoubleArray(double[] array);
  static { System.loadLibrary("PassArray"); }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
      double[] doubleArray = new double[1_000_000_000];
      passDoubleArray(doubleArray);
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
}
```

and the native code has no other calls than calls to `JNI` stuff

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_recipeNo026_PassArray_passDoubleArray
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass obj, jdoubleArray array) {

  printf ("Double array\n");
  jboolean isCopy;
  jdouble *doubleBody = (*env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(env, array, &isCopy);
  (*env)->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(env, array, doubleBody, JNI_ABORT); 
}
```

memory consumptions seems to be pretty stable in both: Java heap and native code. And you can see how native memory is being allocated and released while code proceeds.

[image]

[image]

I'd definitely start looking for the leak in parts of the code that are called from your `JNI` wrapper.

Also, be aware of the fact, that native memory can grow even though you don't call native code at all (e.g. `JNI`). After all, Java have to make allocations using `malloc` for it's own heap at some point. Take a look here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int size = 10;

    double [][] array = new double[100][1];

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
      array[i] = new double[size];
      size = size * 2;
      System.out.println("Allocating: " + size);
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

  }
```

there is no `JNI` call anymore. Now, let's run the app.

```
> java -Xmx4G -Xms512m -Djava.library.path=:./lib -cp target recipeNo026.PassArray
library: :./lib
Allocating: 20
Allocating: 40
Allocating: 80
Allocating: 160
Allocating: 320
Allocating: 640
Allocating: 1280
Allocating: 2560
Allocating: 5120
Allocating: 10240
Allocating: 20480
Allocating: 40960
Allocating: 81920
Allocating: 163840
Allocating: 327680
Allocating: 655360
Allocating: 1310720
Allocating: 2621440
Allocating: 5242880
Allocating: 10485760
Allocating: 20971520
Allocating: 41943040
Allocating: 83886080
Allocating: 167772160
Allocating: 335544320
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at recipeNo026.PassArray.main(PassArray.java:25)
```

and let's take a look at native memory consumption (over time) of Java process.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my question. By "leaks in parts of the code called from the JNI wrapper" do you mean the Java side? If that is the case, how could it be that I am getting memory allocations on the native code side?

Comment: Not really. Inside your JNI code you call some native functions like some `Tauc` related stuff. Try removing all that code and see what happens when you do nothing at all in JNI apart from handling Java array.